# Trying to create a socket between servers with SocketIO and PHPws

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io, phpwebsocket, phpws

I'm having a bit of an issue with websockets. So, I have a Rpi that provides me some data through a socketIO client in a pretty simple way. The following code shows how do I get to get this data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <title>SocketIO test</title>
    <script src="http://192.168.5.5:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var client = io.connect('http://192.168.5.5:8000');
        client.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connected');
        });
        client.on('raw', function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
        client.on('state', function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

However, what I need to implement is a little bit more complex. I need to use a Apache server to trait some of the data before it gets to the client side. The following image shows what I attempt to build:

[image]

To reach my goal I tried several WebSocket Servers and Client libraries for PHP until I found [PHPws](https://github.com/Devristo/phpws), which looks like the best solution for my scenario.
So, I read the examples, I test them and everything went well until I tried to connect to the Rpi with the following code:

```
require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");
$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream("php://output");
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$client = new \Devristo\Phpws\Client\WebSocket("ws://192.168.5.5:8000", $loop, $logger);
$client->on("connect", function() use ($logger, $client){
    $logger->notice("Or we can use the connect event!");
    $client->send("Hello world!");
});
$client->on("raw", function($message) use ($client, $logger){
    $logger->notice("Got message: ".$message->getData());
    $client->close();
});
$client->open()->then(function() use($logger, $client){
    $logger->notice("We can use a promise to determine when the socket has been connected!");
});
$loop->run();
```

I've more or less taken [this example](https://github.com/Devristo/phpws/blob/master/examples/echo_client.php) from Devristo's github.

From the server side, the execution of the program is not throwing any error or message.

Is it possible to build what I want to build here with PHPws?
If so, am I connecting properly to de Rpi server with PHPws sample code shown?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible :

**[Node] Socket Server** (This would be your `RPi`)

Simple socket.io server in node to check for a
    (success) client connection event.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(1337);
io.on("connection",function(socket){console.log("[+] client",socket.id);})
```

**[PHP] Socket Client**

Using [`Elephant.IO`](https://packagist.org/packages/wisembly/elephant.io) we setup a client ([Client Example for Socket.IO v2.0](https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io/blob/master/example/socket.io/2.x/emitter-with-headers/client.php))

```
<?php
use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version2X;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Client(new Version2X('http://localhost:1337', [
 'headers' => [
   'X-My-Header: websocket rocks',
   'Authorization: Bearer 12b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i'
 ]
]));
$client->initialize();
$client->emit('broadcast', ['foo' => 'bar']);
$client->close();
```

---

With this simple Client/Server example you will see the 'on connection' event in the node server when the browser opens the `client.php`